# BindingList(of T) to List(of T)

Tags: vb.net

I am passing a BindingList(Of T) to a List(of T) and i am experiencing that the value of the List keeps updating itself with the value of the DataGridViewSuppliers.DataSource

```
mInitialValue As New List(Of T)
Private Property DataSource As BindingList(Of T)
    Get
        If DataGridViewSuppliers.DataSource Is Nothing Then
            DataGridViewSuppliers.DataSource = New BindingList(Of T)
        End If
        Return CType(DataGridViewSuppliers.DataSource, BindingList(Of T))
    End Get
    Set(value As BindingList(Of T))
        DataGridViewSuppliers.DataSource = value
    End Set
End Property

  DataSource = lElements
  mInitialValue = lSuppAccounts.ToList()
```

All I want is to save the initial value of the binding list to a separate list.

Comment: You are likely accidentally reassigning or updating `mInitialValue` somewhere if it is getting changed along with `lSuppAccounts` (?)  Its not clear how/if `lSuppAccounts` is that DS/BindingList.  But ` mInitialValue = lSuppAccounts.ToList()` creates a new list and saves it. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/dL7GtX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BindingList(Of T) inherits from the List(Of T) so when you pass it over, it doesn't create a copy, it just allows you to use all those feature of a List(Of T). At anytime, you could then pass that List(Of T) back to a BindingList(Of T) and then use it's features. It's called Polymorphism. You are not making copies of the data, you are passing around memory pointer to the original list.

What you want is a copy of the data that is not a memory pointer but it's own memory space. To do this, you can use the `CopyTo()` method of the list. It will make a copy that you can then put into another list.

Comment: i will mark this as answer because you are right in the first part which lead me to the correct solution, however CopyTo() does not create a hard copy